# mp4 file won't play in ipad?

Tags: html, ipad, mp4, jwplayer

i have this mp4 file called bunny.mp4 , that im trying to play in ipad, which works fine in chrome and firefox, im using the jwplayer:

i did ffmpeg on the mp4 file to get the info:

this what i get:

```
 metadatacreator : Yet Another Metadata Injector for FLV - Version 1.4
    hasKeyframes    : true
    hasVideo        : true
    hasAudio        : true
    hasMetadata     : true
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    datasize        : 403006663
    videosize       : 321220617
    audiosize       : 80076198
    lasttimestamp   : 6376
    lastkeyframetimestamp: 6376
    lastkeyframelocation: 403034889
  Duration: 01:46:15.99, start: 0.042000, bitrate: 505 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 624x352 [SAR 1:1 DAR 39:22], 400 kb/s, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 96 kb/s
```

are these video spec fine to play in the ipad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like it is a flv file, you can run ffmpeg to convert it to mp4 file.
./ffmpeg -i  -acodec copy -vcodec copy

after that you may want to convert it to fast start file using ffmpeg tool.
./qt-faststart